# Will deleting Google account also delete my Adsense account?

Tags: google-adsense, youtube, gmail, accounts

I really want to delete my Google Adsense today at any cost because I have another Adsense account which i can add but it cant verify because of having same location.

The real problem is the old Adsense account which I want to delete wants me to verify its location with the 6 digit pin before closing it. It is added with my Youtube channel still.  Even though I tried removing it, and it should be removed by now. I still don't know how is it even added and how can I delete this account.

I definitely don't need the old Gmail account, so I'm really need of help to know if deleting the Gmail would also delete my old Adsense account.